# openssl_verify(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a public key for a .pem file

Tags: php, openssl

Currently attempting to read a `.pem` public key to verify it through `openssl`.

```
/**
 * Check whether the signed message sent back by the server is
 * correct or not.
 */
function check($str, $MAC)
{
    $fp = fopen(
        dirname(__FILE__) . '/rsa_public_key.pem',
        'r'
    );

    $cert = fread($fp, 8192);

    fclose($fp);

    $pubkeyid = openssl_get_publickey($cert);

    return openssl_verify($str, $MAC, $pubkeyid);
}
```

With that said, upon executing my script, I receive this error:

`openssl_verify(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a public key in some/path at line X`

Originally, I wrote this function to accept `.cer` certifications. Here's an explanation of the difference between all these [different key formats](https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file). To my understanding `.pem` are similar to `.cer`, however, I could not for the life of me figure out how to allow my script to read my `.pem` file.

My question is - what do I need to do in order for my function to read this public key?

EDIT: Upon some Googling, I have tried using `file_get_contents()` to a particular path but I would receive the same error.

What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Upon opening this `.pem` file, it was all in one line. It appears each line requires the length of 64 characters, so I made sure each line was 64 lines, and it successfully parsed. Had nothing to do with `.cer`.

Comment: You mean you made sure each line was 64 chars?

Comment: Each line of the Base64 block, I presume, not the header/footer lines.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage, answer would have more value with code in it.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage any chance we could continue conversation in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137297/room-for-eugene-and-thegreencabbage?

Answer (score 10):

In addition, the `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----` lines should contain **exactly five** dashes on each side. No more, no less. Six is right out.

There may or may not be a newline at the end of the final line.

Windows line endings (CR/LF) are allowed, even on *nix-hosted PHP.