# Does JWT RS256 requires OpenSSL? Can't decode JWT in Php

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, jwt

Our certificate is Comodo Positive SSL.
We are trying to decode JWT which is gived from "Sign with Apple Id API" using Php with https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt this library.
When we run decode it gives us

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: openssl_verify(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a public key

Filename: php-jwt/JWT.php

Line Number: 231

Array ( [status] => [message] => OpenSSL error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line )
```

We don't know what to do.. If we change RS256 to HS256 it gives us

```
Array ( [status] => [message] => Algorithm not allowed )
```

Comment: sounds like your public key is knackered. Open it up and double check it looks normal

Comment: check this guys answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406753/openssl-verify-supplied-key-param-cannot-be-coerced-into-a-public-key-for-a

Comment: @delboy1978uk Problem is we don't use Open SSL, we using Comodo Positive SSL. I don't know is this works with Comodo Positive SSL.

Comment: the error message confirms that you are indeed using open SSL

Comment: Is my misunderstanding or you are trying to "decode" a JWT that was generated by others (Apple)? Usually: JWT is ENCODED with just Base64 encoding (three parts separated by dots) which is not requiring any certificate to be decoded. Then the last part is a signature (here certificates may, not necessarily, be involved) and this part you are not expected to be able to deal with if is generated by others. They (the creator of the JWT) only will be able to VERIFY THE SIGNATURE (not decoding indeed).

Comment: Yes I trying to decode JWT that was generated by Apple and no Base64 decode don't work. I need to decode JWT. This official JWT website decode my key perfectly https://jwt.io/ I'm trying to implement this to Php.

Comment: I also use [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) for some tests. The only things it does is decoding Base64 encoded parts of the JWT. Note that every iniividual part, separated by the '.' (dot) character has to be decoded on its own because '.' (dot) is not a valid Base64 character. This decoding is not related to any certificate or encription, In fact it is just ENCODING. Anyone can decode JWT, but the security (just confirming autenticity of info and not hiding them) comes from the signature (last part). This is how JWT is made.

Comment: @DiegoMazzaro Got it. Thank you so much for these information. I look up JWT.php file and I see how its done, as you say its seperated dots and use urlsafeB64Decode. I got the payload succesfully thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JWT is a token string which is composed by three parts separated by a dot `'.'` character.

Each part is **Base64-encoded** (not encrypted) so you can get the content of each part by Base64-decoding each part individually. Since Base64-encoded data does not contain the dot `'.'` characters this gives the possibility to use it as a separator to join the three parts in any case.

The content of the three sub strings, once the JWT has been split and each individual part Base64-decoded is as follows:

- algorithm used for the signature
- informative content in JSON format
- signature

So in order to retrieve the information brought by the token it is needed to:

- Split the JWT at dot `'.'` characters
- Take the second part and `Base64-decode` it

It has to be considered that the information contained in a JWT is NOT protected by being read, it is protected against modification; so there is nothing wrong in being able to decode and access this information without knowledge of certificates or encryption keys.

The whole process related to the token has three actors:

- the **issuer**: usually an authentication API
- the **bearer**: usually the API client application
- the **consumer**: usually the API which requires it to respond

The third part of the token, the signature, is the element that allows the consumer to be sure the token has not been modified and, for that reason, that the information contained in it can be trusted because had been checked/provided by the issuer.

The bearer is not expected to be able to check the token: it is just expected to receive it from a verification procedure and give it to the API it wants to use. It can eventually access the content, meaning that in the context of the application an access to the token information **by the client that received it** does not have to constitute a vulnerability. The token has to be delivered to the client (and sent back to the consumer) over a protected channel like SSL / https and this is to protect access to the token **by other entities**, not by the client which the token is being delivered.

The consumer and issuer are often (but not necessarily) just different API methods of the same application.

The algorithm used for the signature can be a symmetric or asymmetric encryption one.
In the first case the encryption key has to be shared between the issuer and the consumer. Although this may seem a problem it actually is not the case in situations (a quite common case) where the issuer is also the consumer (or at least they are in the same host). In this case the "shared secret" is indeed not shared with anyone.

When the consumer (one or more) needs to be separated by the issuer then an asymmetric encryption can be used so that the issuer keeps the private key and the consumer just have the public key. In this case of course also a symmetric encryption can be adopted but the "shared secret" has to be really shared with the different consumers so evaluations must be done if this can be safely done and maintained.