# Verification and Validation of JWT Token on server and client side

Tags: jwt, digital-signature

I am trying to understand the validation and verification of JWT tokens when using Web APIs. The call flow is as follows:

A = Client

B = API Server

1. A -> B: A sends a requests to Server with user name and password.  ( This is HTTPS so using TLS encryption)
2. B : Authenticates the client A.
3. B-> A: Sends back a JWT token back to A. Assuming that B is using "Asymmetric Key Encryption". B creates a header with {alg:RS256 typ:JWT} and it adds some claims. And then B creates the signature by hashing header + payload, and then signing it with private key of B.
4. A: A receives the token

Question: Does A need to validate the token it has received from B? If yes, it will need the PUBLIC key of B. Also, if B were to use a "symmetric key algorithm", then A also needs the "shared secret" or the key which B used to sign the token.

5. A -> B: A needs to make a API call to B. A needs to include the token in the Authorization header:

Question: Assuming that "Asymmetric Key Encryption" was used earlier. Will A now just add the token as it was received in the Authorization header. Or A will create a hash of payload and claims, and then sign it with it's own Private Key.

Question: Assuming that A had just used the token as is, when B receives this token, what is B supposed to do? Validate the token using B's public key ....or just a string compare of the token suffice, to validate. Of course B will need to look at the claims :) :) .
Assuming that A had signed the token with it's private key. Then B needs to know the corresponding Public key to validate the token. But if B were talking to multiple clients will it then need each clients Public key ?

At this time I am just trying to understand how things are supposed to work. The examples implementations that I have seen are using "Symmetric Key Algorithm" and the client just accepts from server and uses it as is for the next API calls. Seems a bit odd to me, if the token is compromised then we are in trouble.

Comment: Try to see if this answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59771281/1943428

Comment: @DiegoMazzaro this does help a lot and clears it for me. Thank you so much for the reply.